# estimate the upper bound for the number of the nodes of length $l$

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-theory

I have a graph $G=(V,E)$, where $V$ is a vertex set, and $E$ is an arc set. Now given a vertex $i\in V$, I want to find the (small) upper bound for the number of the nodes in $V$ that has the length of $l$ from $i$.

For example, when $l=1$, we can find the degree of vertex $i$, $deg(i)$, is the good upper bound for the number of the nodes in $V$ that has the length of $1$ from $i$.

When $l=2$, maybe $deg(i)*deg_{\max}$ is the upper bound for the number of the nodes in $V$ that has the length of $2$ from $i$, but $deg(i)*deg_{\max}$ seems a bit larger bound.

For the general case $l$, are there any small upper bounds ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An upper bound is
$\deg(i) (\deg_\max - 1)^{\ell-1}$.  This is best possible in the sense that it is exact in the case of a tree where $i$ is the root, all leaves are at distance $\ell$ from the root, and all nodes other than the root and the leaves have degree $\deg_\max$.

Comment: But for each level of the tree, many vertices may be the same. Are there any small bounds to get rid of those same vertices in the same level of the tree?

Comment: If it's a tree, they are not the same.

Comment: Thank you. BTW, are there any chances to find a bound in terms of the average degree, rather than $deg_{\max}$.